# VB.NET: Data to Ruby

Tags: ruby, vb.net, encryption

So I made an application that will generate some useful data, in VB.NET.
And I also have a Ruby application, which should be able to read and interpret such generated data.

But I am unsure of a lightweight, fast and secure way to do so. I mean, I need my VB.NET application to generate all those arrays/strings/numbers, compress them into one file, and somehow read the file's contents in Ruby without problem. Preferably, the user being unable to edit the data files.

Have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use YAML or JSON as the intermediary format. If you don't want the user to edit the data files, zip them and/or perform some other obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

You might find working with XML easier than with JSON or YAML in .NET, and on the Ruby side it's roughly the same.

As for disabling edits, you can use some form of signing (say, have header and body in your XML, body carying the useful data, make the digital signature of the body and write it in the header).